# Unrecognized option: --module-path Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx, vscode-extensions

trying to setup a JavaFX project for the first time on vscode

error keep showing:

Unrecognized option: --module-path
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
PS C:\Users\bisce\Desktop\coding\JavaProjects\FirstJavaFXProject>

I tried setting up the env variable _JAVA_OPTION to have 1GB of memory allocated.

attaching a screenshot of the launch.json file:
[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsY2i.png)

Farewell

I tried setting up the env variable _JAVA_OPTION to have 1GB of memory allocated.

Comment: Welcome to Slackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also don't use images for text information https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: Which Java version is being used? `--moudle-path` is not available with Java 8 or earlier

Comment: @user16320675 java version "20.0.1" 2023-04-18

Comment: are you sure, how you checked? (e.g. adding `-version` to `vmArgs` *before* `--module-path` ?)  (( I get the exact error when trying it with Java 8, but I do not use VS code ))

Comment: @user16320675 i checked the version by entering “java -version” in the cmd. So i should add “-version $myversion” before —module-path?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure you are using **Java9** or higher, then configure [`vmArgs` in *launch.json*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_launch):

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "App",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "application.Main",
            "projectName": "FirstJavaFXProject",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path C:/Java/java-sdk-20.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",

        }
    ]
}
```

*No single quotes around the path.*

***It will be more helpful to refer to [this document](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).***

[image]

Comment: That’s interesting: an image of a cited web page *and* a link to the page in bold italics.  I’ve never seen that before in an answer.  It works well here IMO.